# Why was 1407 Graymalkin Lane chosen as the address for Xavier's Mansion?

Tags: marvel, x-men

The [Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Mansion) for Dr Xavier's school gives its address as 1407 Graymalkin Lane.  But the Google maps satellite view of that address looks nothing like the school. And the movies use this [English estate](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Englefield_House) the set for the school. **Why did Marvel choose this actual address?**  Did a Marvel employee live at this address?

Comment: This is only distantly related, but it's cool: The address of Avengers Mansion was given as 890 Fifth Avenue in Manhattan. Wandering around the city one day, I went to that address, but it didn't exist. There *is* a property between the 880 and 900 blocks, and there's a mansion there: the Frick Collection museum. But it faces one of the side streets, so its address is 1 East 70th Street.

Answer (score 4):

Your supposition was correct. This address was chosen by X-Men writer Chris Claremont, an alumnus of Bard College, New York, a short hour's drive from Westchester. It's likely that he would have been able to physically visit the supposed location and pick out a nice quiet street to situate the (fictional) location of Xavier's School of Witchcraft and Wizardry.

> *Chalk it up to Chris Claremont. A comics writer who took over the
>   then-failing X-Men franchise in the 1970s and brought it back to
>   fruition by penning several classic story arcs and focusing on
>   character development, Claremont attended Bard as an undergraduate.
>   “What’s the point of going to a great school if you can’t make it a
>   slightly supporting character in a cool comic series?” he told
>   Almanac. Claremont admits that making Annandale Jean Grey’s childhood
>   home was his call, but says that he wasn’t aware of Professor X’s
>   relationship to Bard.*
>
> *Claremont recognized the importance of tethering the fantasy world of
>   comics to the real world. “The location of Xavier’s School in
>   Westchester County is something originally established by Stan [Lee]
>   in the opening issues of the series,” says the author. **“My
>   contribution to that rubric was to take his general placement and give
>   it more specificity, creating a street address and a real sense of
>   place. Its proximity to New York was a matter of convenience and
>   publishing policy: Everyone at Marvel was located in or close to New
>   York – unlike DC, where the JLA [Justice League of America] characters
>   were placed in fictional analogues for the real world (Metropolis,
>   Gotham, Star City and the like).** This way, writers and pencilers could
>   frame the story’s events within a common physical reality familiar to
>   both creators and readers. Everyone’s writing and drawing and reading
>   what they all know, which (for me, anyway) makes the adventures that
>   much more plausible and a whole lot more fun.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[Many comic book heroes have Hudson Valley roots](https://hudsonvalleyone.com/2015/01/24/many-comic-book-heroes-have-roots-in-the-hudson-valley/)</sup></sub>

As to why he chose this specific address, it's worthy of note that Claremont cites Shakespeare as one of his [key influencers](http://www.cbr.com/bcc-spotlight-on-chris-claremont/). It's certainly possible that he was attracted to the location because of its connotations with Macbeth, Greymalkin being the familiar of one of the three witches, a spirit disguised as a humble cat in the same way that Xavier's academy belies a secret identity as the home of the X-Men.

> **First Witch:** *Where the place?*
>   **Second Witch:** *Upon the heath.*
>   **Third Witch:** *There to meet with Macbeth.*
>   **First Witch:** ***I come, Greymalkin!***
>
> <sub><sup>[Macbeth: Act 1, Scene I](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/macbeth/full.html)</sup></sub>

Comment: OK, but why 1407?

Comment: Here is the satellite view of 1407 https://www.google.com/maps/place/1407+Graymalkin+Lane,+North+Salem,+NY+10560/@41.3364814,-73.5977191,18z/data=!3m1!1e3!4m2!3m1!1s0x89c2acfbe860a7dd:0x27b6ec9ed00fd6cd

Comment: @CodeMed - Good question. Dunno. The number might have some significance for Claremont

Comment: *Xavier's School of Witchcraft and Wizardry* umm... Okay..  Is that the same fiction where Sauron built the death star? :p

Comment: @JonClements - I couldn't remember the proper name. Something about gifted students?

Comment: Umm "for gifted youngsters" is probably the best known one - although fairly sure it's changed names and even locations at times...

Comment: I guess I am wondering why choose an actual address when they could choose a number that is not a real house.

Comment: @CodeMed - The road is real (although it's a dirt lane, not a proper road). There are only two properties on the road and the number is completely fictitious

Comment: Given that there are only two properties on the street and the X-Mansion has the same street address as one of the houses, it is statistically impossible for Marvel to have made up the numerical portion of the address..

Comment: @CodeMed - Assuming you're talking about the address on Google Maps, I think you'll find that that was added by x-men fans and isn't a real address.

Comment: @Valorum What evidence of this can you provide?

Comment: @CodeMed - Google said so; https://www.indy100.com/article/the-xmen-mansion-now-exists-in-the-real-world-according-to-google-maps--e1m32p-ove